# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'quarter' for DateTimeField or join on the field not permitted

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to filter objects by date of creation and sort them quarterly.

I have a sample model like this

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

then I have another model that connects with the Assets model this way,

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
    assets = models.ManyToManyField(Asset)

 // i want to find all assets created by quarter and here is what I tried

    def assets_total_quarterly(self):
        q1= self.assets.filter(created_at__quarter=1)
        return q1
```

I get this error

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'quarter' for DateTimeField or join on the field not permitted.`

I followed the example here and have looked up similar questions but none solves my problem
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#quarter

Comment: What Django version do you use?

Comment: django v1.11...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `Django 1.11` but `quarter` appeared in 2.0 only:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.0/#models

So use `Django v2.0` at least if you want to use a `quarter`

Answer (score 1):

its not with the `quarter` but with the join you are trying to do.

```
   def assets_total_quarterly(self):
        q1= self.objects.filter(assets__created_at__quarter=1)
        return q1
```

Comment: this error came up after running this 
```ValueError: Exception raised in callable attribute "assets_total_quarterly"; original exception was: Manager isn't accessible via Portfolio instances```

Comment: remove the self and put Portfolio in the query and try once like `Portfolio .objects.filter(assets__created_at__quarter=1)`

Comment: Same error as the original...my bad it's the Django version as Sergey has pointed out, this isn't available in django 1.11. Thanks all the same!